# how would you convert a java application with multiple classes each with its own frames into an applet

Tags: java, applet

I have a  java application with multiple classes each with its own frames. If I want to go to another class, i would close or hide current class frame and start the new class frame. If i want to go back to the old class, I would close new class frame and start or make visible old class frame, how would I do this in applet?

part of my main class

```
private static void createAndShowGUI() {

        //Create and set up the window.
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("MDCAP");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);

        //Set up the content pane.
        addComponentsToPane(frame, frame.getContentPane());

        //position the frame in the center 
        frame.setSize(350, 500);
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setVisible(true);
```

in my main class, if i want to go to another class

```
        //close the frame and run contractInfromation
        button4.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                frame.setVisible(false);
                frame.dispose();
                contractInformation.main(null);
            }
        });
```

Comment: *"I have a java application with multiple classes each with its own frames."*  That is where this GUI starts to go wrong.  Here are 3 alternatives.  1) `CardLayout` 2)  `JDesktopPane`/`JInternalFrame`(s) 3) 1 `JFrame` with multiple `JDialog` instances.

Comment: @AndrewThompson you would not recomment JPanels in general? It depends rather on the GUI I guess.

Comment: @owlstead A nested layout containing many components is something I often recommend, but it did not sound 'right' (or at least not 'top 3') for this use-case.  Two factors that decided that were that the app. was currently in frames, and that the OP wanted aspects of it to appear and disappear on demand.  The latter is doable in a nested layout, but a little tricky.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Opening a frame each time will not make for a user friendly application. You are better off using JPanels and put the right one into the Applet or JFrame (or whatever component) when it is required.

Comment: A `CardLayout` would be excellent for swapping those panels.  :)  And I think I misunderstood your earlier comment to me.  ;)

Comment: Should have removed "in general" - I use *way* too many adjectives *in general* :), thanks for the thumbs up.

Answer (score 3):

I think I would convert it to [Webstart](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/deployment/deployment-guide/contents.html). Probably much easier - potentially no code changes!

Comment: In fact, it can often be done with almost _no_ changes to the code.

Comment: I feel [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info) is a great alternative for deploying this GUI, and will give this a +1 even though it might be argued it should have been made as a comment.  ;)

Comment: WebStart is slightly more difficult, but with applets you run inside the browser, and one might run out of memory. Of course you could turn your JFrames in your own `class FramePanel extends JPanel` and replace in your applet FramePanels.

Comment: @JoopEggen *"WebStart is slightly more difficult,"* Than ***applets***?!?  Hardly.  The only thing which is more difficult about JWS is that it requires all resources to be in a Jar.  The (many) things that are difficult about applets *start with* 'browsers' (and applet/JRE/browser interaction problems).

Comment: Well, and that the jars must be signed for webstart :) -- but I take your comment wrt to my 'answer' is really a comment. Its true! But, honest, I'm trying to be helpful! I really think not having to modify your application in order to deploy it (ie, go with webstart) is probably 'the way to go'.

Comment: @AndrewThompson I thought a small hint was needed about the extra infrastructure required (applets are static and need no serverside java). But yes, JWS is one of the finest deployment/environment techniques for desktop applications (JEdit, ArgoUML). Furthermore I wanted to warn *against* applets.

Comment: @JoopEggen  I have plenty of JWS projects without a hint of the `JNLPServlet`, so 'no - JWS does not *require* server side Java'.

Comment: @dsummersl  *"the jars must be signed for webstart"*  Rubbish they do.  They only need to be signed if requesting extended permissions (the same is true of applets).  But then, a sand-boxed (non-JWS deployed) applet cannot achieve what a sand-boxed JWS app. can do.

Comment: @AndrewThompson really, thanks for clearifying that. I cannot guess why I never learned that.